# How can I prevent Android from auto-installing all of my apps?

Tags: google-play-store, sync

I usually install different ROMs regularly...

When I set up my account on a fresh ROM, I don't want my phone to start loading all of the apps that I had installed with the same account on previous ROM. I want to choose what I want reinstalled on a new version.

Can I control this behaviour or is there a another way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to disable the auto-restore under `Menu -> Settings -> Privacy -> Automatic restore` before installing a different ROM.

Comment: automatic restore i had disabled for about a month.. in fact i havent checked the option to backup my data even..for more than a month..

Answer (score 0):

On most ROMs (if not all) there's a checkbox after logging in to your Google account in the initial setup wizard which allows you to enable backup/restore for the device. If you deselect this checkbox, your apps will not be automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

After you flash a new ROM, you are usually asked to log-in to your Google account. If I remember correctly, one of the (wizard) steps has a checkbox that will ask if you want to sync your account, or re-install the apps that you installed previously.

Is it possible that you missed this step and just moved to the `Next` screen?